# How to declare the labels in one line?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
Instead of writing below three lines how can I declare them in 1 line?

  Label sub1 = (Label) GridView1.Rows[0].FindControl("Label5");
  Label sub2 = (Label) GridView1.Rows[1].FindControl("Label5");
  Label sub3 = (Label) GridView1.Rows[2].FindControl("Label5");
```

If I put "i" instead of "0" or "1" 0r "2"  it is showing the only the value of "2" .So I want that all how to write them in one line?

```
The code is:

for (int i = 0; i < ds.Rows.Count; i++) {
  Label price = (Label) GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("Label5");
  TextBox ttlqnt = (TextBox) GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("TextBox1");
  decimal y = decimal.Parse(ttlqnt.Text);
  Label pricecal = (Label) GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("Label2");
  decimal z = (y * decimal.Parse(price.Text));
  pricecal.Text = "Rs." + (z.ToString());
  Label sub1 = (Label) GridView1.Rows[0].FindControl("Label5");
  Label sub2 = (Label) GridView1.Rows[1].FindControl("Label5");
  Label sub3 = (Label) GridView1.Rows[2].FindControl("Label5");
  TextBox ttlqnt1 = (TextBox) GridView1.Rows[0].FindControl("TextBox1");
  TextBox ttlqnt2 = (TextBox) GridView1.Rows[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
  TextBox ttlqnt3 = (TextBox) GridView1.Rows[2].FindControl("TextBox1");
  decimal c1 = decimal.Parse(ttlqnt1.Text);
  decimal c2 = decimal.Parse(ttlqnt2.Text);
  decimal c3 = decimal.Parse(ttlqnt3.Text);
  decimal y1 = c1 * decimal.Parse(sub1.Text);
  decimal y2 = c2 * decimal.Parse(sub2.Text);
  decimal y3 = c3 * decimal.Parse(sub3.Text);
  decimal y4 = y1 + y2 + y3;
  Subtotal.Text = y4.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I am wondering why you would want to? The code is more readable without that being in a loop.. unless of course the number of rows is dynamic.

Comment: I want to modify because when any row value (i.e 0/1/2) is absent it is showing error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
decimal zTotal = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < ds.Rows.Count; i++) {
  Label price = (Label) GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("Label5");
  TextBox ttlqnt = (TextBox) GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("TextBox1");
  decimal y = decimal.Parse(ttlqnt.Text);
  Label pricecal = (Label) GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("Label2");
  decimal z = (y * decimal.Parse(price.Text));
  pricecal.Text = "Rs." + (z.ToString());

  zTotal += z;
}

Subtotal.Text = zTotal.ToString();
```

I removed `sub1`, `sub2`, `sub3` because you have that value in `price` already.
I added a `zTotal` that will keep the sum for all the values in the loop, instead of the hardcoded `y1 + y2 + y3`

Answer (score 0):

You have no other option than pulling that declaration inside a loop; though I don't see why can't you define them separately likewise you are already doing

```
List<Label> labels = new List<Label>();

for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
  labels.Add((Label)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("Label5"));
}
```

Comment: This is fine if I declare them separately.But the difficulty is not here it is in Label sub1 = (Label) GridView1.Rows[0].FindControl("Label5");
  Label sub2 = (Label) GridView1.Rows[1].FindControl("Label5");
  Label sub3 = (Label) GridView1.Rows[2].FindControl("Label5");